# query category wise dara

Tags: dataset, data-mining, data-cleaning, databases, sql

I have stored the some products and there respective category in sql.
[image]

Like this. Now I want fetch all product from table with respective category.
output should be=>
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to explain, precisely, how the output is obtained from the input.

Comment: `name` is the set of all distinct products and categories, and `flag_for_ca` is a bit field (Y/N) if the `name` is a category??

Answer (score 1):

assuming your products table is called `products` the following sql statement would achieve this

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id, category as name, 1 as flag_for_ca FROM products
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT id, prodct as name, 0 as flag_for_ca FROM products
```